# Get the single value of a sql result set

Tags: php, sql

Consider this SQL query

```
$sql = "select count(*) as count from table where value='this'";
```

This query is going to return only one value in the field `count`.

Is there a way to get that value without using a `fetch_array` and pointing the first value of the returned array instead?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Oddant: I solved your problem. You can find it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) will allow you to pull the value directly from the result set without having to use a *fetch* method. Here's a very simple example of how you can use it to get your single value:

```
mysql_select_db( "mysql", mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) );
$r = mysql_query( "SELECT count(name) as total FROM `help_keyword`" );
echo $r ? mysql_result( $r, 0 ) : mysql_error() ; // Outputs 450
```

There are three parameters for the `mysql_result()` function; first is the result set itself, second is the row index and third is the field index. I'm only using the first two parameters since the third one will default to 0, the first field returned.

Comment: nice way to do it, thanks Jonathan and thanks for the trick of testing the result ha :D

Comment: @Oddantfr You're welcome. Thanks for using StackOverflow, and for giving me the opportunity to discover `mysql_result()` which I hadn't known about before your question :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson ha great skill your searching was quite fast, to be honest I was aware of this function, I already did use it but I was hoping find a function to get a integer just passing the sql_query response and returning the value of the first row/first field. If you find one just give me an head up ! :D

Comment: @Oddantfr That's what this function is doing: `mysql_result( $r, 0 )` gives you the first value of the first row in the result (the results of count()). Am I misunderstanding your request? The `$r` is the result set, which is necessary for the function to know which data set to look at, the second is the row index and the third ( defaults to 0 ) is the field index. From what I can tell, this function does exactly what you're seeking.

Comment: no no I got it right ! I'm just a little picky and tried to avoid the a second parameter (or a third one in this case).

Comment: @Oddantfr If it means that much to you, you could wrap it in your own function: `function getFirst( $r ) { return mysql_result( $r, 0 ); }` and call it: `$total = getFirst( $result );`.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson oh yes never thought of it, it was quite late when I posted the message and at this time brains are hibernating hum.. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Oddantfr I know what you mean :) Glad I could help either way.

Answer (score 1):

As a sql beginner I too wasted a lot of time trying to use these one-dimensional outcomes of sql queries directly. I thought that since the result is not an array I could skip these while-loops with those fetch_arrays.

However, only now I realise that although the outcome may be the integer value of 8, as long as you do not convert it to the value it is, it is still considered as just a 'query-result' instead of an integer.

Jonathan's code helped me realise this. For myself, I used a slightly different code that helped me out. Here is what worked for me:

```
$con=mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");

if(!$con)
    {die('could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
$db_selected=mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$sql = "the sql query that yiels one value, for example a SELECT COUNT query";

$outcome_considered_as_a_query-result-set = mysql_query($sql,$con);

$outcome_considered_as_the_one_element_of_the_result_set = mysql_result($outcome_considered_as_a_query-result-set,0);

echo $outcome_considered_as_the_one_element_of_the_result_set;

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql);
```

Just don't use count in this case. Select everything and this will count it.

Comment: $mysql_num_rows will not work for you a select count statement

Comment: @Anze Why do you think PHP's `mysql_num_rows()` is better than MySQL's `COUNT(*)`? Please, explain.

Comment: Doing the `select */numrows` version is highly inefficient. You force MySQL to fetch/parse/prepare data rows and then throw them away.

Comment: Well if you use Count(*) the whole deal of counting will be done on the sql server which will result in less data needed to be sent from sql server to the php server. On the other hand, if you are a bit lazy :), you can parse the whole data set from the sql server with SELECT * and do the counting on PHP. It depends on how many records you expect to have in your table.

Comment: I admit it is more efficient to use Count(*) but he asked what is the fastest written (coded) way to do so.

Comment: I guess preparing the data with sql functions is a better way, even for the clarity of the php code and for the gaining performance

Comment: Well I'm going to use Jonathan Sampson's suggestion, this way sounds the best one to me :)